# How to use a jar file with another jar file

Tags: java, jdbc, jar, executable-jar

I have created a program that uses the JDBC driver jar, so that I can use databases inside my program. It works fine when I run it from the IDE, but when I put the files into a jar, the program does not function properly, showing the same problems as when I try to run it without the JDBC drivers within the IDE. Is there any way I can access the JDBC drivers from the jar file?

Comment: how do you try to run it?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I click on the jar file. It opens, and when I click on a button that should show a table with the database information, nothing happens